# groupBy and mapValues or map and toMap

Tags: scala

What's the best in performance?

```
all.groupBy(_.id).mapValues(_.head)
```

Or

```
all.map(l => (l.id, l)).toMap
```

Cheers

Comment: "[If you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster then race your horses](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general the only way to answer is to benchmark it, and on JVM the best approach for benchmarking is [JMH](http://nitschinger.at/Using-JMH-for-Java-Microbenchmarking).

However, for this specific case it'll strongly depend on usage pattern of the result, among other things. `mapValues` doesn't actually apply the function to values, it's only done when the result `Map` is accessed. So if e.g. you'll access it once and not for all keys, I'd expect `mapValues` to be faster, while if you access the same key repeatedly, `map` might end up faster. Thus you shouldn't just benchmark these snippets without using the result.